# How can i fix array index out of bound of my java code?

Tags: java

Hey guys can anyone help me in my problem about array index out of bound in my java code. Below is my full code having a problem.

```
public static double calculateMedian(double[] arr) {
    double[] sortedArr = sortarr(arr);

    double median;

    if (arr.length % 2 == 0) {
        int indexA = (arr.length-1) / 2;
        int indexB = (arr.length) / 2;

        median = ((double) (sortedArr[indexA] + sortedArr[indexB])) / 2; // this code has a error in index out of bounds.
    }   
    else {
        int index = (sortedArr.length - 1) / 2;
        median = sortedArr[ index ];
    }
    return median;  
}
```

This is my sorting fucntion

```
 public static double[] sortarr(double[] arr) {
    boolean performedSwap = true;
    double modeValue;

    while(performedSwap) {
        performedSwap = false;

        for (int i=0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
            modeValue = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = modeValue;

            performedSwap = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: what does `sortarr(arr)` do?

Comment: You are clearly passing an empty array. Show the code of the `main` function.

Comment: the sortarr(arr) has a values of sorted numbers.

Comment: Put a debug point at the line of failure and make sure that the `arr` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

if `arr.length = 0` (empty array) your code try to take `sortedArr[0]` and you have this exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly passing an empty array.

Add an extra condition before checking for `arr.length % 2 == 0` to see if `arr.length == 0`.

Not sure what you would want to return as the median in that case.

Comment: Bro my sorting function has an empty array to pass into the another fucntion?

Comment: No not your sorting function. Your main function.

Answer (score 0):

The only case where the error can happen is if your array is empty. The median for empty array is none since there is no value to begin with.

```
public static double calculateMedian(double[] arr) {
    double[] sortedArr = sortarr(arr);

    double median;

    if (arr.length == 0) {
        return ; // return nothing if it is an empty array
    } else if (arr.length % 2 == 0) {
        int indexA = (arr.length-1) / 2;
        int indexB = (arr.length) / 2;

        median = ((double) (sortedArr[indexA] + sortedArr[indexB])) / 2; // this code has a error in index out of bounds.
    } else {
        int index = (sortedArr.length - 1) / 2;
        median = sortedArr[ index ];
    }
    return median;  
}
```

Comment: Bro when i use your code my other function has affected.

Comment: which one of your function that get affected?

Comment: Bro what exactly to be returned?

Comment: This fucntion has been affected.
public static double getMin(double[] arr){
            double min = arr[0], max = arr[0];
}

Comment: so, the result from `calculateMedian` function will be used for other functions?

Comment: No, only the arr will be used to the another functions.

Comment: for what i see in your code, `arr` doesn't change. try to change the median into 0 if the length of `arr` is 0 and see what happens.